# is this why this fraction turns from a negative to a positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So here is this problem

-x+3/2=0

when solving for a solution by elimination in linear algebra, you are supposed to move the fraction 3/2 to the other side in order to get the constant "x" by itself. So I subtract the fraction to the other side in order to get:

-x=-3/2.

because I assume that it's zero minus 3/2 which makes the fraction a negative? then I divide -x from both sides which yields x=3/2. It turns positive since a negative divided by a negative is positive. Is this logic correct?

thank you for your time!

Comment: Alternatively, starting from your original equation, "move" the $x$ to the other side by adding $x$ to both sides. You will get the same result, $x = \frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

From
$$-x+\frac{3}{2}=0$$
it is easiest to **add** $(1x)$ to both sides, to get
$$\frac{3}{2}=x.$$

If however you prefer for some reason to have all terms in $x$ on the left hand side, and all constants on the right hand side, than indeed you'd **subtract** $(\frac{3}{2})$ from both sides, leaving you with
$$-x=-\frac{3}{2}$$
which is then to be **multiplied** by $(-1)$ (and not *divided* by $(-x)$ as you wrote), so that
$(-1)(-x)=(-1)(-\frac{3}{2})$ which is again $$x=\frac{3}{2}.$$
So, changing signs is easiliest achieved by multiplying by $(-1),$ or more precisely: the phrase "change of sign" is associated with the generation of the **additive inverse** (negation, which is multiplication by $(−1).$

Comment: subsequently, take this problem -x+3/2=1 if you move the x to the other side, it will result in 3/2=2x. Divide both sides and you get 3/4. which is the wrong answer versus if you subtract the 3/2 first. you get the answer 1/2 I know I'm doing something wrong with the x

Comment: @AaronValenzuela Moving the $x$ to the other side should give $x+1=\frac{3}{2}$. Now subtract $1$ from both sides to get the correct answer.

Comment: i understand. everyone I appreciate the help i now understand what I was doing wrong and understand the sequence. I was trying to add the coefficient of x into the constant 1 on the other side which you cannot since they are different. or simply remembering that I'm just moving it to the other side. Thank you again!